# How to determine if a checkbox with wildcard has been checked

Tags: jquery

Question, but let's say I have a couple of checkboxes that get their ID's derived dynamically, however both checkbox ID's will contain a prefix of `'someVal_'`

With Jquery, I'm trying to determine if any of the checkboxes have been selected, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
if ($('[id^=someVal_]').prop('checked').length > 0){
   //logic
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.prop('checked')` returns the value of the property in the first element matching the selector. So it just returns `true` or `false` for the first checkbox.

Put `:checked` in the selector to filter to the checked boxes, and get the length of that.

```
if ($('[id^=someVal_]:checked').length > 0){
   //logic
}
```

Comment: you could shorten this to `if ($('[id^=someVal_]:checked').length){` since it evaluates to true if it finds any matching elements. +1 though.

Comment: @RyanWilson I'm not a big fan of that abbreviation. I think it's best to write `> 0` to make clear that you're counting something, especially in an educational context like this.

Comment: To each their own, still gave you an upvote. Have a good day :)